# Apache Usergrid Build error on buildling Usergrid Launcher

Tags: apache, maven, usergrid

Hi I am trying to do a fresh build of Apache Usergrid but have been running into a build error when it reaches the Usergrid Launcher. The following is the log that gets displayed when I run: mvn -X clean install -DskipTests=true
Am I correct that it seems to be pointing to Apple Java Extensions to be the cause of the problem? If so how do I go about fixing the issue?

```
[DEBUG]    junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[DEBUG]       org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[DEBUG]    org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:test
[DEBUG]    org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[DEBUG]    log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[DEBUG]    com.apple:AppleJavaExtensions:jar:1.5.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for file://D:\incubator-usergrid-master\incubator-usergrid-master\stack\launcher/../m/repository
Downloading: file://D:\incubator-usergrid-master\incubator-usergrid-master\stack\launcher/../m2/repository/com/apple/AppleJavaExtensions/1.5.4/AppleJavaExtensions-1.5.4.jar
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\Alex\.m2\repository\com\apple\AppleJavaExtensions\1.5.4\AppleJavaExtensions-1.5.4.jar.lastUpdated
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/apple/AppleJavaExtensions/1.5.4/AppleJavaExtensions-1.5.4.jar
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\Alex\.m2\repository\com\apple\AppleJavaExtensions\1.5.4\AppleJavaExtensions-1.5.4.jar.lastUpdated
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Usergrid Parent .................................... SUCCESS [01:29 min]
[INFO] Usergrid Java SDK (old) ............................ SUCCESS [  8.208 s]
[INFO] Usergrid Build Tools ............................... SUCCESS [  0.955 s]
[INFO] Usergrid Config .................................... SUCCESS [  1.616 s]
[INFO] Usergrid Test Utils ................................ SUCCESS [  9.847 s]
[INFO] Usergrid Core ...................................... SUCCESS [ 31.411 s]
[INFO] Usergrid Services .................................. SUCCESS [ 27.583 s]
[INFO] Usergrid MongoDB Emulator .......................... SUCCESS [ 10.643 s]
[INFO] Usergrid REST ...................................... SUCCESS [01:02 min]
[INFO] Usergrid Tools ..................................... SUCCESS [13:34 min]
[INFO] Usergrid Websocket ................................. SUCCESS [ 27.734 s]
[INFO] Usergrid Launcher .................................. FAILURE [ 21.943 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18:27 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-08-28T00:05:29-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 58M/178M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project usergrid-launcher: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.usergrid:usergrid-launcher:jar:1.0.0:
Could not find artifact com.apple:AppleJavaExtensions:jar:1.5.4 in local-dependencies (file://D:\incubator-usergrid-master\incubator-usergrid-master\stack\launcher/../m2/repository) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project usergrid-launcher: Could not resolve dependencies
for project org.apache.usergrid:usergrid-launcher:jar:1.0.0: Could not find artifact com.apple:AppleJavaExtensions:jar:1.5.4 in
local-dependencies (file://D:\incubator-usergrid-master\incubator-usergrid-master\stack\launcher/../m2/repository)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:220)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:257)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for
project org.apache.usergrid:usergrid-launcher:jar:1.0.0: Could not find artifact
com.apple:AppleJavaExtensions:jar:1.5.4 in local-dependencies
(file://D:\incubator-usergrid-master\incubator-usergrid-master\stack\launcher/../m2/repository)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDpendencyResolver.java:195)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact
com.apple:AppleJavaExtensions:jar:1.5.4 in local-dependencies (file://D:\incubator-usergrid-master\incubator-usergrid-master\stack\launcher/../m2/repository)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:192)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact
com.apple:AppleJavaExtensions:jar:1.5.4 in local-dependencies (file://D:\incubator-usergrid-master\incubator-usergrid-master\stack\launcher/../m2/repository)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact
com.apple:AppleJavaExtensions:jar:1.5.4 in local-dependencies (file://D:\incubator-usergrid-master\incubator-usergrid-master\stack\launcher/../m2/repository)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :usergrid-launcher D:\incubator-usergrid-master\incubator-usergrid-master\stack>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I just hit this as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly its missing in a repo somewhere, for now get the jar from 
https://code.google.com/r/ahduros-ooo-maven/source/browse/repository/com/apple/applejavaextensions/1.5.4/

and install it locally with

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DpomFile=<path-to-pomfile>
```

You also have to either hack the jar or the pom.xml for launcher around a bit. I did the latter:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.apple</groupId>
  <artifactId>applejavaextensions</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is the <path-to-file> the path of where the launcher is?

Comment: Path to the downloaded jar and pom files.

Comment: Ah alright. I noticed what my problem was with the mvn install:install-file. I needed to include the jar file in the path while before I just gave it the path to where the file was located without indicating the file itself. Thank you for the help.